# Wrong FSharp.Core version looked for in a Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, f#, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms project I am getting an error on Windows 8.1 and UWP:

```xml
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=3.259.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

The actual version of F# used throughout the solution is 3.7.4.0:

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile7</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<TargetProfile>netcore</TargetProfile>
<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>3.7.4.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

There is an F# PCL project and C# platform-specific projects. The error occurs only when using F# libraries from Nuget in the PCL. These packages tend to use:

```xml
<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>3.259.3.1</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
```

I have tried the following, but they do not change the error:

- Putting an app.config file with a binding redirect to 3.7.4.0 in the F# project and/or the build directory
- Installing the FSharp.Core Nuget package into all projects

Very grateful for any help.

**Edit:** in the original question there was an incompatibility between the profile (111) and the intended TargetFSharpCoreVersion (3.7.4.0) which was causing additional issues.